# ES6, make a very little function

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

Sorry for the silly question...

Is there any possible way to make this function a little bit more smaller?.

```
const handleOk = () => {
    ok()
    handleClose()
  }
```

I was thinking in something like this:

const handleOk = (ok)(handleClose).

What is that? curry?

thnaks!

Comment: Chasing shorter code often leads to much less readable code. Of all the factors that contribute to good code, length (in number of lines) should be the absolute last and least important. This code is fine as is, you're doing two separate things, so they should be on two separate lines. If you want to do them both on the same line, just use the function `handleOk` since it does both but only takes a single line to call.

Comment: It will make little difference to the machines if you use comma operator or rename the `handleClose` function to `hc`. We write code for humans, not machines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I probably shouldn't join in the code golfing here, because you should always prefer readability over terseness when you have to choose between the two, but nevertheless, here's two options:

If the first return value is falsy (any function that has an implicit empty return of `undefined`, for example), then using the OR operator will ensure that both functions get called during the return, and you can use the arrow function implicit return.

```
const handleOk = () => ok() || close()
```

However, if there is a chance that your first function will return something truthy, this would create a bug where sometimes the second function doesn't get called, as the OR condition would be satisfied by the first function's return value, and your `handleOk` function will return that value and be finished.

One way to ensure both functions will get called and keep it all on one line is the comma operator, which is heavily discouraged by nearly all style guides, but also heavily used by code minifiers (read some minified code some time, and you'll see lots of comma operators), so it's perfectly valid javascript.

```
const handleOk = () => (ok(), close())
```

The parentheses are necessary to group the comma-operated statements together, otherwise the interpreter would find that comma too ambiguous and break your program in its confusion. The way the comma operator works is it evaluates each comma-separated statement in order, then returns the value of the final statement, regardless of it's truthy/falsy-ness.

One final point to mention, which should hopefully discourage this behavior: in your original question you asked about writing a particular function shorter, and the options given here use an implicit return, which means the function will return the value of one of the other functions. However, in your original example, nothing was being returned, so these functions are not equivalent. This may seem like a trivial detail in view of your whole app, but nevertheless I mention it because there are always much larger and more significant concerns than keeping your syntax short.

Readability is king:

```
const handleOk = () => {
  ok()
  handleClose()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your complete explanation. Btw here is the full React project [link](https://github.com/josuevalrob/jeval-web/blob/master/src/components/misc/Alert.js#L17)